# When i use laravel DB class i get error column name not found

Tags: php, laravel

> Hello everyone
>   i am having some trouble with laravel DB class

```
    $arr = ['onoma', 'epitheto'];

    $data = "'".implode("', '", $arr) . "'";

    $content =  DB::table($name)->pluck($data);
```

**When i do it manually like**

```
$content = DB::table($name)->pluck('onoma','epitheto');
```

Everything is working fine. But with `implode()` functions i get this error

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''onoma', 'epitheto'' in 'field
>   list' (SQL: select `'onoma', 'epitheto'` from `xrister`)

Comment: try once `$data = "'".implode("','", $arr)."'";`  remove all the spaces

Comment: Again im getting same error
'Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''onoma','epitheto'' in 'field list' (SQL: select `'onoma','epitheto'` from `xrister`)'

Comment: did you removed all spaces?

Answer (score 3):

In the example that works fine you are passing 2 arguments to that method call.

`pluck($column, $key)` 2 separate arguments

`pluck('column', 'key')`  2 separate strings

In the one that doesn't work you are passing a single string as 1 argument. You are telling `pluck` to use the single column named `'onoma','epitheto'` for some reason.

`pluck("'onoma', 'epitheto'")`   1 string, 1 argument

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5.6 + then you can use the `splat` operator:

```
 $arr = ['onoma', 'epitheto'];

 $content =  DB::table($name)->pluck(...$arr);
```

If not then you can do:

```
 $arr = ['onoma', 'epitheto'];

 $content = call_user_func_array([ DB::table($name), 'pluck' ], $arr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works with the splat operator